# Can this be fixed before poly?

Tags: finishing

[image]

Just starting to get my feet wet on this old table, sanded and stained it. The picture shows the defect I'm talking about and it was there before I started refinishing the table.

Is this something the person who made the table did by sanding too hard and if so would me sanding around it help any? Is there any way to make this look better?

Here is the picture of the whole table and the defect is at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Do you know if the table is veneered or solid wood?  To me this looks like someone sanded through the veneer.  If so there's really nothing you can do for it short of re-veneering the whole panel.

Comment: Nevermind my question, I just saw the second photo.  This tabletop clearly is veneered.  I think you're out of luck here...Unless someone has some idea I haven't thought of.

Comment: Probably nothing can fix the grain, but color might be blended a bit better by staining the whole table in something darker than original color. Maybe using less penetrating stains, like gel or even stain+poly. It's a step to try before painting anyway :)

Comment: I appreciate all the help thanks.I figured they had went through the veneer

Comment: I would take a stain which is darker than the surrounding wood and *quickly* hit the sanded thru area, feathering the edges, then wipe is off fairly quickly. You might have to do this a few times to blend it in.

Comment: I am hoping that you did not sand through the veneer, very gently sand with a fine grit paper (220 or so)  following the grain and try reapplying the stain you might get lucky, I think you will as i can still see the grain in the veneer.      I have had fair results by starting with a coloured poly (like Poly-Shades) and artist oils to match the colour use a wire brush or ink to mimic the grain.

Comment: The natural assumption here is this tabletop is veneered, which was my first thought also. But can you tell if by looking at the sides and ends whether the frame is also veneered or are those solid wood? This wouldn't be an uncommon method of construction. If they are solid the grain will continue over the edges and down the sides and ends. It's very hard to be tell from just the one photo but I'm wondering if the problem might be an area of cross-grain scratches in a low spot (so less easily erased by subsequent sanding) rather than veneer that has been sanded through to show the substrate.

Comment: If you'll be sticking around, please provide more details about every aspect of what you've done in a Question like this. Just telling us you've sanded and stained isn't enough info. Pretend we know nothing about the project (cos we don't haha) and describe everything you've done. How you sanded (power and/or hand), what grits you used and the *exact* staining product you used can all be critical pieces of info.